# MinHeight on resizeable Expander

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I'm trying to create a style which automatically makes all my Expanders resizeable, by embedding the Content inside a Grid with a GridSplitter.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Expander">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0" Background="Red">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{Binding ???}"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" MinHeight="{Binding ???}"/>
                        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" Background="Green" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                               ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander Grid.Row="0" IsExpanded="True" Header="Expander...">
        <Border Background="Blue" MinHeight="200" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black"/>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Grid.Row="1" IsExpanded="True" Header="Expander...">
        <Border Background="Blue" MinHeight="100" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black"/>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

What I can't work out is how to Bind the MinHeight of the RowDefinition (or the ContentControl) inside the style to the MinHeight of the Content of the Expander.

*(Note, the garish colours are just to see what's what...)*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how dinamycally you need that and if that solves your issue:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="GridRowDefinition" Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="GridRowDefinition2"  Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And in the style

```
<Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0" Background="Red">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{Binding MinHeight, ElementName=GridRowDefinition}"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" MinHeight="{Binding MinHeight, ElementName=GridRowDefinition2}"/>
                            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" Background="Green" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
```

Because I do not see why you place content in the expander if you add a border inside the expander. I hope it helps

Comment: The border inside the expander is just a placeholder to test embedding content, it could have been anything else. And unfortunately the MinHeight I want to bind to is not the one you have in your first snippet: it's the MinHeight of the Content/Border.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me: looking at the debug output indicated that `{Binding}` relates to whatever the Content is (in this case the Border). So simply doing `{Binding MinHeight}` on the RowDefinition (inside the Style.DataTemplate) had exactly the required effect.

Next step: work out how to memorise and restore heights :)